# How can I create a clickable link to my website in my Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

I would like to offer a link to my website in my Facebook profile (not page). I understand that there is the option to add a link under the "Info" tab, but I would like the link to appear in or near the "About" section of the "Timeline".

Is that possible?